# How can I define some functions individually for each interface of my class?

Tags: c++, com

I am learning COM, also I am a beginner in C++. I defined three interfaces:

```
#include <objbase.h>

// pure abstract base class
interface IX : IUnknown{  
  virtual void __stdcall Fx() = 0; // pure virtual function
};

// pure abstract base class
interface IY : IUnknown{
  virtual void __stdcall Fy() = 0; // pure virtual function
};

// pure abstract base class
interface IZ : IUnknown{
  virtual void __stdcall Fz() = 0; // pure virtual function
};

extern "C"{
  extern const IID IID_IX;
  extern const IID IID_IY;
  extern const IID IID_IZ;
}
```

Then I create a class with implementation of these interfaces:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IFace.h"

// COM component
class CA :
  public IX,
  public IY,
  public IZ
{
public:
  CA();
  ~CA();
  virtual void __stdcall Fx(); // IX
  virtual void __stdcall Fy(); // IY
  virtual void __stdcall Fz(); // IZ
  // IUnknown (this interface implemented by IX, IY and IZ)
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID& iid, void** ppv);
  virtual ULONG __stdcall AddRef();
  virtual ULONG __stdcall Release();
private:
  // Each interface has own counter (for convenience of debugging)
  ULONG ix_counter;
  ULONG iy_counter;
  ULONG iz_counter;
};
...
```

I want to use the separate counter of instances for each interface (for convenience of debugging). How I must define `AddRef()` and `Release()` function at this case?

I can do it such:

```
ULONG __stdcall CA::AddRef(){
  // increase interface counter here
}
```

But this code is *common* for `IX`, `IY` and `IZ` instances of my `CA` class. If instance is `IX` then I need increase the `ix_counter` counter only. If instance is `IY` then I need increase the `iy_counter` counter only, etc.

I tried such approach:

```
virtual HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID& iid, void** ppv); // common implementation
virtual ULONG __stdcall IX::AddRef(); // for IX instances
virtual ULONG __stdcall IX::Release(); // for IX instances

virtual ULONG __stdcall IY::AddRef(); // for IY instances
virtual ULONG __stdcall IY::Release(); // for IY instances

virtual ULONG __stdcall IZ::AddRef(); // for IZ instances
virtual ULONG __stdcall IZ::Release(); // for IZ instances
```

instead of

```
virtual ULONG __stdcall AddRef();
virtual ULONG __stdcall Release();
```

Also I tried:

```
// This is wrong definitions:
ULONG __stdcall CA::IX::AddRef(){
  return InterlockedIncrement(&ix_counter);
}

ULONG __stdcall CA::IX::Release(){
  InterlockedDecrement(&ix_counter);
  ULONG count = ix_counter + iy_counter + iz_counter;
  if (0 == count) delete this;
  return count;
}
```

instead of

```
ULONG __stdcall CA::AddRef(){
      // increase interface counter here
    }
```

But my last replacement is wrong.

How can I define `AddRef()` and `Release()` functions individually for each interface?

Comment: Consider using ATL - it has this facility [built in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sycfy8ec.aspx). The way ATL does this is by generating per-interface thunks (fragments of machine code) on the fly at run-time - so not for the faint of heart. But that's largely because it tries to be minimally invasive on your class' structure. If you don't mind an invasive solution, and you don't want to use ATL for some reason, then go with something along the lines of the example by @RomanR .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a counter specific to interface. Your code could look like this:

```
// (interfaces defined)

template <typename T, typename Base>
class CUnknownWithCounterT :
    public Base
{
public:
    ULONG m_nCounter;

public:
    CUnknownWithCounterT() :
        m_nCounter(0)
    {
    }
    ULONG __stdcall AddRef()
    {
        m_nCounter++;
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->InternalAddRef();
    }
    ULONG __stdcall Release()
    {
        m_nCounter--;
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->InternalRelease();
    }
};

class CA :
    public CUnknownWithCounterT<CA, IX>,
    public CUnknownWithCounterT<CA, IY>,
    public CUnknownWithCounterT<CA, IZ>
{
public:
    ULONG m_nMainCounter;

public:
    // QueryInterface as stuff...
    ULONG __stdcall InternalAddRef()
    {
        return ++m_nMainCounter;
    }
    ULONG __stdcall InternalRelease()
    {
        return --m_nMainCounter;
    }
};
```

Ready to go:

```
CA A;
IX* pX = &A;
IY* pY = &A;
IZ* pZ = &A;
pY->AddRef();
pZ->AddRef();
pZ->AddRef();
_tprintf(_T("%d %d %d\n"), 
    A.CUnknownWithCounterT<CA, IX>::m_nCounter, 
    A.CUnknownWithCounterT<CA, IY>::m_nCounter, 
    A.CUnknownWithCounterT<CA, IZ>::m_nCounter, 
    0);
// 0 1 2
```

However you need to also override QueryInterface respectively because it also returns a pointer in the way that respective counter needs an increment.

The implementation will be COM compliant (`m_nMainCounter` is having that counter for COM), the question is whether individual counters are accurate in helping you find reference leaks. If they are helpful most of the time, then you certainly have them useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: `Even though it is basically legal to AddRef on one interface, and Release on another` It is [explicitly illegal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692481.aspx) to do so: "From a COM client's perspective, reference counting is always done for each interface. Clients should never assume that an object uses the same counter for all interfaces." A client that `AddRef`s through one interface and `Release`s through another if in violation of COM rules - in other words, is buggy.

Comment: Actually, reference management is per **interface pointer**, so for instance, you cannot legally `QueryInterface` for `IX` and `AddRef`, then `QueryInterface` for `IX` again and `Release`.  You must match call to `AddRef`/`Release` on the **same interface pointer**, so in the example I just gave, you must `Release` the original `IX` pointer.  Nonetheless, this answer's code is correct in implementing separate counters per interface.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use the separate counter of instances for each interface (for convenience of debugging). How I must define AddRef() and Release() function at this case?

This is totally in violation of COM rules. One of the requirements is that whenever you retrieve `IUnknown*` through any pointer of any type that points to a specific object you get the same pointer value. This is why you simply cannot have a separate counter in any meaningful way.

Comment: I know about this requirement and I keep it. Existence of several counters doesn't violate this requirement. It is very convenient for debugging mode.

Comment: @Bush How will you know which counter to update when the user first retrieves `IX`, then `IUnknown`, then `IZ`, then `IUnknown` again?

Comment: The conclusion doesn't follow from the premise. COM very explicitly defines reference counting as to be on a per-interface basis. There are [certain exotic implementation techniques](http://www.369o.com/data/books/atl/0321159624/ch06lev1sec4.html) that rely on this feature. In your example, you would first increment the reference count on `IX`, then on one interface that's chosen to be the object's identity (may or may not be a standalone `IUnknown` implementation), then on `IZ`, and then on the object identity again.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Good, and what if I have `IX` implicitly upcast to `IUnknown`?

Comment: What then? I'm not sure I get your point. Of course it does - every COM interface implicitly upcasts to `IUnknown`.

Comment: Although it's valid to upcast any interface pointer to `IUnknown`, it's invalid to return a different `IUnknown` interface pointer when querying for `IID_IUnknown` for the **same object**, even though the querying is done on different **interface pointers**.  It's perfectly possible to have a separate counter per interface, since it's even possible to have a counter per interface pointer (e.g. having all interfaces except `IUnknown` implemented as uncached tear-offs).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should inherit the common implementation from a class implementing IUnknown. That would parallel what COM defines.